# What are the uses of axis properties of openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl, axis, linechart

I would like to know the use of below properties when drawing line charts with openpyxl, as I am unable to find explanation on the purpose of them.

**crossAx**=100

**c2.y_axis.axId** = 200

**c1.y_axis.crossAx** = 500

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198694/chart-with-secondary-y-axis-and-x-axis-as-dates Have you found this link?  It doesn't explain it fully but better than the documentation.